# PDO Issue with UPDATE statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to update a row in my table and i have come into a pickle.

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `players`(`plusadd`,`takeaway`,`dsum`,`msum`) 
    VALUES (:plusadd,:takeaway,:dsum,:msum) WHERE username = :username");
    $stmt->execute(array(
    ':username' => $_SESSION['username'],
                    ':plusadd' => $plusadd,
                    ':takeaway' => $takeaway,
                    ':dsum' => $dsum,
                    ':msum' => $msum,               
                ));
```

I get the following error i have stripped the parts that are not relevant

```
'(`plusadd`,`takeaway`,`dsum`,`msum`) VALUES 
('2','3','5','1')where username = 'd'
```

it also refers to the line `));`

i am not sure where the username `d` is coming from as the username im using is demo

here is the full error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' 
with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or 
access violation: 1064 You have an error in your 
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near '(`plusadd`,`takeaway`,`dsum`,`msum`) 
VALUES ('2','3','5','1')where username = 'd' at 
line 1' in www\grade.php:54 Stack trace: #0 
www\grade.php(54): PDOStatement->execute(Array) 
#1 {main} thrown in www\grade.php on line 54
```

Comment: `':username' => $_SESSION['username'],` to `':username' => $username,` - while making sure `session_start();` is loaded.

Comment: Interesting, @Fred-ii-, why would you think this works? I think it's no coincidence that the first letter of 'demo' is in the query. Maybe it's some kind of unicode issue.

Comment: Because, he has assigned it to a variable. @GolezTrol shouldn't it be the way to use it? I don't know why OP is assigning it in the first place.

Comment: I know, but assigning it to a variable doesn't remove it from `$_SESSION`, does it?

Comment: The only reason that might work is if the session were closed between the assignment and usage. Is this a db error or php error? I'm assuming PHP because the database shouldn't even see the `));` line. Depending on your PHP version/config it may have an issue with the training comma on `$msum,` perhaps?

Comment: I'm baffled by this too. Some form of constraint somewhere? @GolezTrol

Comment: Aaaugh, missing `SET` if you want to UPDATE - You want `INSERT into`, tended to think, **if** you want to insert and not update; what do you want to do?

Comment: You are mixing up `INSERT` syntax with `UPDATE` syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html  `UPDATE players SET plusadd = :plusadd, takeaway = :takeaway... WHERE username = :username`

Comment: I thought with UPDATE you had to use set 'plusadd'=:plusadd.  This looks more like an insert statement

Comment: thank you to everyone for all your help @Fred-ii- thx for the fix that got it working :)

Comment: @thenashone TBH, I noticed Mike's comment *after* I was formulating an answer.

Comment: sorry yes you did :) the comments came in a bit to quick for me lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *may* be wanting to do an INSERT into, not an UPDATE, so I'm led to believe.

```
"INSERT into `players` (`plusadd`,`takeaway`,`dsum`,`msum`) ...
```

otherwise, if you want to do an UPDATE, you need to use `SET`

I.e.:

```
"UPDATE `players` SET plusadd = :plusadd, takeaway=:takeaway, dsum=:dsum, msum= :msum...
```

if an UPDATE is what you wish to do.

Otherwise, use `INSERT INTO`

- That's why you're getting an SQL error.

Comment: Many thanks, its sad that i have been on this problem for 5 hours. lol

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up the syntax for INSERT versus UPDATE.

UPDATE goes like this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column = value, column = value, ... 
WHERE condition;
```

INSERT goes like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (columns...) VALUES (values...);
```

Insert does not support a WHERE clause, because if you're inserting a new row, the row is naturally not there yet, so it makes no sense to look for it with a WHERE condition.

MySQL supports an alternative syntax for INSERT, that makes it look similar to an UPDATE statement:

```
INSERT INTO tablename SET column = value, column = value, ...;
```

But still doesn't support a WHERE clause.

Comment: *"But still doesn't support a WHERE clause."* - If only a `WHERE` clause were supported, it'd be the greatest thing since sliced bread ;)

Comment: But what would that even mean to put a WHERE clause on an INSERT? Would it make it like REPLACE (but works for conditions on non-unique columns)?

Comment: Very good question Bill. I'll have to think about that one. Unfortunately, I'm just out the door. I'll get back to you on that. I'll definitely give it some thought.

Comment: *...and we're back.* I tend to think that it would be an equivalent to REPLACE, in a matter of speaking, yes. I'm just wondering why you wrote that in the first place lol *"But still doesn't support a WHERE clause."*

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I wrote it because the OP seemed to be using part of the INSERT syntax (the VALUES clause) followed by a WHERE clause. That is not valid syntax in either UPDATE or INSERT or REPLACE.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, As for an REPLACE with a WHERE clause, that's pretty much the SQL:2003 MERGE statement, but MySQL does not support that. See for example http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: *"That is not valid syntax in either UPDATE"* - Actually a WHERE clause is valid for UPDATE Bill http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html - I agree for the others though. Thanks for the SQL:2003 MERGE article.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes, of course WHERE is valid in UPDATE. But a VALUES clause is not part of an UPDATE. So the syntax the OP was using was confused.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand what you mean now Bill, you're entirely right.